# Is Google Cloud Messaging linked to the Mobile SIM card?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

1) If a user mobile device is registered with **GCM**, then will the user mobile get a notification from GCM, if user has changed his SIM?

Or

2) Is it possible to link a SIM with GCM, so no matter how any android phones he upgrades but still recieve the notifications.

Answer (score 2):

1. GCM definitely does not require a SIM card to be present at all. I just setup up a notifications app on an intl Note 3 with no SIM.
2. A notification developer can use multiple unique identifiers to link a user to a notification, but the user doesn't normally have any input as to which the developer chooses to use. In many cases you may be registered anonymously as a class, especially if the notifications are not personalized and broadcast to all users of an app.
3. Keep in mind that GCM notifications are finicky as to when they start arriving after the app is registered. For example, with the Note 3 I just setup, even after rebooting none of the 6 test pushes I sent were received. I also checked/unchecked the app's notification box in application manager (Samsung). I also installed 'Push Notification Fixer' (don't let you dissuade from using this, as it does work to keep notifications prompt after the first).

In this case, it wasn't until I changed Wifi connections that the queue was immediately triggered and flushed to the device. It's annoyingly arbitrary and a pain to debug.

Comment: Just set up firebase cloud messaging, the push notification doesn't seem to work on a phone without SIM card in my case.

Answer (score 0):

> If a user mobile device is registered with GCM, then will the user
>   mobile get a notification from GCM, if user has changed his SIM?

**Yes**, user will get GCM Notification. GCM Notification Flow has nothing to do whether there is any SIM in Device or not.

Also if user has not any SIM in device, Device can registered to the Server and will get GCm Notification.

Comment: so what entity is linked with the GCM? is it IMEI no, google a/c or some other entity

Comment: @aj_blk Yes,User should have register with one google Account in Device. that would be necessary to create your registration ID which will become the entity through which Server will send Push Notification to your Device.

Comment: However, the Google documentation says that: `It uses an existing connection for Google services. For pre-3.0 devices, this requires users to set up their Google account on their mobile devices. A Google account is not a requirement on devices running Android 4.0.4 or higher`. So it has to bear in mind the Android platform version.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to link a SIM with GCM, so no matter how any android
>   phones he upgrades but still recieve the notifications.

Possible, Your app needs to be installed on the devices and register the device and sim id with your server. 
Check TelephonyManager for getting the information you need and then create a database on your server with the relationship between user/sim/whatever(phonenumber?) <-> gcm notification id.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

Basically most apps that send User specific notifications register the user with some identification additional to the device, your sim id can be that identification. you should take into consideration that if a sim is lost then you won't get the same sim id again (it's not your number).